# Custom events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to create custom events (for example, triple click or swipe) in JavaScript that will trigger with certain conditions?  Perhaps to listen to this custom event:

```
addEventListener('trplclick', handler, false);
```

So handler will be called only if 3 clicks were done within 600 ms, for example.

Comment: from client side to server Side ?

Comment: what from client side to server side?

Comment: @AkshayJoy he tagged this with javascript? And the code is js. This is client side?

Comment: you need createevent Handler for Server side event from javascript.?

Comment: How is the browser supposed to know what condition constitutes a `trplclick`? You need to track conditions and trigger such events manually.

Comment: @AkshayJoy that statement doesn't even make sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I listen for triple clicks in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480060/how-do-i-listen-for-triple-clicks-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the `triplclick` event yourself. Listen to the individual click events, count them, and trigger `triplclick` when it makes sense.

Have a look at [`document.dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.dispatchEvent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.dispatchEvent).

I'm using jQuery to demonstrate the concept, but you don't need to:

```
var count = 0;
var resetTimeout - 1;
$(element).on("click", function(){
    count++;
    clearTimeout(resetTimeout);
    if (count === 3)
    {
        count = 0;
        $(element).trigger("trplclick");
    }
    else 
    {
        resetTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            count = 0; // Don't count if no click within the last second.
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See similar question here: [How do I listen for triple clicks in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480060/how-do-i-listen-for-triple-clicks-in-javascript)

Basically what it does is combining double click event and single click event together to mimic triple click. When double click event triggers, set a timeout for 200ms. If there's a following click coming up, check if the timer timed out. If this click happens 200ms later after the previous double click(at this time, timer was set to null in double click handler), discard this click, otherwise count it as a triple click.

For setting custom event in general, I will refer you to Nicholas C. Zakas's blog post: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/09/custom-events-in-javascript/