# How can I count the number of clicks and then send an ajax request with that number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button that I want to run a function that will make an ajax call and update click_count on my db.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'my_url'
        type: 'post',
        data: {id: 1},
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response.click_count);
        }
    });
```

Now, I want to simplify ajax call when user click button quickly.
For example, if user click the button 10 times quickly, i will send request with param like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'my_url'
        type: 'post',
        data: {id: 1, click_count:10}, // click_count=10;
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response.click_count);
        }
    });
```

So I just send 1 ajax request for 10 clicks instead of 10 requests.

Comment: I would read into double/triple click answers like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480060/how-do-i-listen-for-triple-clicks-in-javascript
They should pretty much solve your problem

Comment: This isn't really practical. I'd suggest that you disable the button when the user clicks it, then re-enable it after the ajax call returns. This is the standard way to handle this kind of thing

Comment: Hello @liam, I don't want to prevent multiple clicks.

Comment: Ok, then how do you intend to know when the user has **stopped** clicking?

Comment: @Liam Actually, this is my problem and my question. But it might something like: when button not clicked for like 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Why do you want this? This feels very artificial. If you want a number, then a better UI is to use a number selector or get the user to type a number into a text box. I can't think of any reason why this type of UX would be desirable

Comment: @liam My goals is similar to medium claps button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a timeout and send the request after the user stopped clicking for a specific time.

1. Define a variable outside: `var timeout = null;`
2. Use this code within you click handler (you can play around with the 500ms):

```
clearTimeout(timeout);

timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'my_url'
        type: 'post',
        data: {id: 1, click_count:10}, // click_count=10;
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response.click_count);
        }
    });
}, 500);
```

Comment: You are welcome. Keep in mind to track the click count like in A. Blub's answer

Answer (score 3):

There are some libs for that, but this will work with vanilla js.

```
var click_count = 0;
var click_timeout;
function countIt() {
   if( click_timeout ) {
       clearTimeout( click_timeout );
   }
   click_count ++;
   click_timeout = setTimeout( function() {
       $.ajax({
            url: 'my_url'
            type: 'post',
            data: {id: 1, click_count:click_count},;
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response.click_count);
            }
        });
       click_count = 0;
   }, 1000 ); // 1 Second for next click
}
```