# Have triple click select only a span?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph in my html and an-id-with-dashes. If I doubleclick it only the word is selected. If I triple click the entire paragraph is selected. How do I have triple click (or double click) select only the span? I tried using a div with inline-block but it failed to work unless it was display:block. I also noticed '.' tends to be highlighted. If there's a period after the span (or div) I'd like that to not be selected

Comment: Please add your code you have tried

Comment: Why would I make my post harder to understand? I tried label, input text which didn't let me style so that didn't work. Content, user-select, psuedo elements. I tried enough things to make the post look like html vomit

Comment: @Stan I was about to totally upvote your comment, but actually I need all those examples because I'm trying to achieve that result that you are trying to avoid.

Comment: @Stan, you could, and this is just me spitballing, use words, much as you did in your comment, but in the question, detailing what you tried. I think the main thing is to get code that everyone can work off of that demonstrates the base scenario, the "paragraph in my html [sic] and an-id-with-dashes". Personally, I'm having trouble picturing that.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution 1: `<span>`s in a Flexbox (with weird consequences)

Here's a non-ideal answer that will **hopefully inspire better answers**:

If you wrap the spans in `<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">`, you get what you asked for, but have to choose between several weird side effects:

Weird word wrap:

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <span>Triple click on&nbsp;</span>
  <span>an-id-with-dashes</span>
  <span>.&nbsp;</span><span>Or triple click anywhere here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
</div>
```

If you want non-weird word wrap, replace every space where you want a word wrap to be able to occur by `&nbsp;</span><span>`. A possibly undesired effect is that triple clicking any of the thus newly introduced spans selects only that span:

```html
<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <span>Triple click on&nbsp;</span>
  <span>an-id-with-dashes</span>
  <span>.&nbsp;</span><span>Or&nbsp;</span><span>triple&nbsp;</span><span>click&nbsp;</span><span>anywhere&nbsp;</span><span>here.&nbsp;</span><span>Lorem&nbsp;</span><span>ipsum&nbsp;</span><span>dolor&nbsp;</span><span>sit&nbsp;</span><span>amet,&nbsp;</span><span>consectetur&nbsp;</span><span>adipiscing&nbsp;</span><span>elit,&nbsp;</span><span>sed&nbsp;</span><span>do&nbsp;</span><span>eiusmod&nbsp;</span><span>tempor&nbsp;</span><span>incididunt&nbsp;</span><span>ut&nbsp;</span><span>labore&nbsp;</span><span>et&nbsp;</span><span>dolore&nbsp;</span><span>magna&nbsp;</span><span>aliqua.&nbsp;</span><span>Ut&nbsp;</span><span>enim&nbsp;</span><span>ad&nbsp;</span><span>minim&nbsp;</span><span>veniam,&nbsp;</span><span>quis&nbsp;</span><span>nostrud&nbsp;</span><span>exercitation&nbsp;</span><span>ullamco&nbsp;</span><span>laboris&nbsp;</span><span>nisi&nbsp;</span><span>ut&nbsp;</span><span>aliquip&nbsp;</span><span>ex&nbsp;</span><span>ea&nbsp;</span><span>commodo&nbsp;</span><span>consequat.</span>
</div>
```

### Solution 2: JavaScript

With JavaScript, you can [listen for triple clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6480060) or easier [for double clicks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event) on your `<span>` and let them trigger [the selection of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/).